# How to find document by calculated date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this document :

```
{ 
    "_id" : BinData(0, "RUBR58qePxvfGqR7WjpkiQ=="), 
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2020-02-05T18:30:14.152+0000"), 
    "retention" : NumberInt(24)
}
```

I want to find all documents where `creation_date < (mygivendate) + retention`

Why when I do

```
db.getCollection("test").find({
  "creation_date":{
    "$gte":{
      "$inc":[ISODate("2010-09-18T16:27:07.000+0000"),"retention"]
    }
  }
})
```

it returns me nothing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$inc` is an update operator and therefore can't be used to find documents. See the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

But here is an example of the use of `$inc` on your data

```
db.collection.update({
  "creation_date": {
    "$gte": ISODate("2020-02-04")
  }
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "retention": 1
  }
})
```

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UQZ2aL0gPgN)

---

To find your documents where `creation_date < (mygivendate) + retention`

You can do :

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [
      "$creation_date",
      {
        "$add": [
          ISODate("2020-01-05"),
          "$retention"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nJFhBTIuWST)

`$expr` is a mongo operator that allows you to use aggregation expression in find queries.
So here I add a date with `$retention`, and see if it's greater than `$creation_date`

Comment: thanks alexis, is their any way to use it in a find ?

Comment: I want to select all items where creation_date < |mygivendate| + retention